# Finding the row number of the first cell which is a number/isn't a given character

Tags: excel-formula

I apologize if this is similar to other questions, but I don't know Excel well enough to adapt the answers. Given a column whose entries are either the `#` character, a number, or blank, how does one find the row number of the first number? E.g.,

```
       A
-----------
 n  |  #
n+1 |  #
n+2 |  #
n+3 |  0
n+4 |  5
```

should return `n+3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(A:A),ROW(A:A)),1)`

This is an array formula - Enter this formula by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> while still in the formula bar.

The if statement is the array part, this builds an array of row numbers where `ISNUMBER(A:A)` is `TRUE` then `SMALL([],1)` returns the first smallest number from that.